# How do I reverse the order of the data in a TreeSet instance?

Tags: java, treeset

I have a class called Dictionary which is a collection of sorted strings. This class is an extension of the TreeSet class, which means that it uses a Comparator for the sorting. I want to have a reverse method for reversing the order of the data set, but this is unfortunately not possible since TreeSet can't change it's Comparator after initialization. As a workaround I tried to create a new Dictionary instance using a reversed version of the original Comparator, but I can't come up with any way to point `this` to the new object.

Is this possible? Maybe an entirely different solution?

```
public void reverse() {
    Dictionary reversed = new Dictionary(this, Collections.reverseOrder());
    this = reversed; // Obviously not working, but is pretty much what I want to do.
    reversed.storeOnFile("descending.txt");
}
```

Comment: Why not use `TreeSet.descendingSet()`?

Answer (score 3):

Consider returning the new `Dictionary` from your reverse method.

```
public Dictionary reverse(){
    return new Dictionary(this, Collections.reverseOder());
}
```

Or return a `List` or `Set` view from the method.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your class from mutable to immutable. This is what you're doing now:

```
Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
dic.reverse();
```

This is what you should do:

```
Dictionary forward = new Dictionary();
Dictionary reverse = forward.reverse();
```

In general, [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) are preferred.

Comment: What if more words need to added to the dictionary?