# How to implement sorted set in descending order?

Tags: java

I have key, value pairs. The key is a `String` and the values are integers. I would want to sort it in descending order so that the element with the highest value appears first.

How do I sort a sorted set in descending order ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you store your KV pairs in a map?

Comment: I m confused which collection should i use?

Comment: i tried treemap but i wasnot arranging it in descending order

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212412/sort-a-set-in-reverse-order

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reverse the order of the data in a TreeSet instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960970/how-do-i-reverse-the-order-of-the-data-in-a-treeset-instance)

Comment: if you have a TreeMap, then it has a descendingMap() method, which return desc sorted collection of elements

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with TreeMap, for example:

```
//any not sorted map
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("567", 567);
map.put("456", 456);
map.put("123", 123);

//create sorted TreeMap with descending sorting
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
sorted.putAll(map);
```

If you wish to sort it by values, then you can make it so:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> sortByComparator(Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap) {

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortedMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                           Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: I am using collection first time?

Comment: itarat over it via it's entries:
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }

Comment: iterating or sorting?

Comment: So, then I need to see your code, to tell, what is wrong

Comment: hey is it sort the map by key only?

Comment: Yes, just by it's key

Comment: is there anyway to sort it by value

Comment: ok thanks  ,  I make some changes like I exchange the key and value pairs but now another issue all the elements are not adding into it only first element is added in map

Comment: changed the answer, added sorting by value